# Why isn't my function to plot growth over time working?

Tags: r, function, dataset

I want to create a function that plots the growth (or Cover as described in the dataset) of a plant species inside of a plot over time. In other words, I want to plot Cover over Date for one species in one plot over time.

Here is an example of the dataset:

```
Site Date        Plot Species Cover 
mbs  2020-04-05  A1   Cest    2
mbs  2020-05-05  A1   Cest    10
mbs  2020-06-05  A1   Cest    15
mbs  2020-07-05  A1   Cest    20
mbs  2020-08-05  A1   Cest    16
mbs  2020-04-05  A3   Frve    1
mbs  2020-05-05  A3   Frve    5
mbs  2020-06-05  A3   Frve    10
mbs  2020-07-05  A3   Frve    12
mbs  2020-08-05  A3   Frve    10
```

Here is also my attempt to make my actual data set reproducible:

```
dput(PlantComp[3000:3040, c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6)])
structure(list(Site = c("umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs"), Date = structure(c(18417, 18417, 
18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 
18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 
18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 
18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 18417, 
18417, 18417, 18417), class = "Date"), Plot = c("B4", "B4", "B4", 
"B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B4", "B5", "B5", "B5", "B5", "B5", 
"B5", "B5", "B6", "B6", "B6", "B6", "B6", "B6", "B6", "B6", "B6", 
"C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", 
"C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2"), Species = c("Cest", "Poco", "Popr", 
"Ruac", "Litter", "Umsp", "Ulsp", "Vert_Litter", "Ptaq", "Cest", 
"Poco", "Popr", "Litter", "Bare_Ground", "Umsp", "Vert_Litter", 
"Cape", "Cest", "Dasp", "Hype", "Poco", "Litter", "Vert_Litter", 
"Ulsp", "Ptaq", "Cest", "Dasp", "Hype", "Popr", "Ruac", "Litter", 
"Umsp", "Vert_Litter", "Ulsp", "Bare_Ground", "Vear", "Cape", 
"Cest", "Dasp", "Hype", "Popr"), Cover = c(6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 78L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 3L, 7L, 76L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 1L, 
4L, 79L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 68L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 19L, 2L, 1L, 3L)), row.names = 3000:3040, class = "data.frame")
```

I did this to the date column as well:

```
PlantComp$Date <- as.Date(PlantComp$Date,
                          format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

This is the code I've tried to write in R to create the desired function:

```
perc_cover_plot <- function(Species, Plot) { 
        PlantCompSub <- filter(PlantComp, Species == Species & Plot == Plot) 
        return(plot(Cover ~ Date, data = PlantCompSub))
}
```

When I call the function `perc_cover_plot <- (Cest, A1)`
I get this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDdEi.png). I seem to get the same plot no matter which species or plot I put into the function.

I've also tried piping to get the desired result:

```
perc_cover_plot2 <- function (Species, Plot) {
        PlantComp %>% 
        filter(Species == Species & Plot == Plot) %>% 
        plot(Cover ~ Date)
}
```

I'm looking to create a basic line graph - something that looks similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOij3.png).

Comment: You're not calling your function the correct way. You said you called your function this way: `perc_cover_plot <- (Cest, A1)` ; you should call it like this: `plotOut <- perc_cover_plot(Species = "Cest", Plot = "A1")`

Comment: I suspect you may need to add some data for "Cover"? Currently the data provides four dates for 8 species. And how do you want the plot(s) printed? one at a time as individual plots or is it OK the plots are faceted i.e. in a grid of individual plots?

Comment: @Peter sorry about that. The "Cover" is added now. It's ok if the plots are in a grid of individual plots.

Comment: Thanks, although you've got `Cover`, there is only one date, which makes for a dull plot. Maybe the thing to do is to extract first 10 rows from 4 or 5 different dates for all the necessary variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is yet another issue of scoping variables with the same names in different environments. The easiest way to bypass that is to rename the variables internally before applying the filter.
Example:

```r
PlantComp <- read.table(text="Site Date Plot Species Cover
mbs 2020-04-05 A1 Cest 2
mbs 2020-05-05 A1 Cest 10
mbs 2020-06-05 A1 Cest 15
mbs 2020-07-05 A1 Cest 20
mbs 2020-08-05 A1 Cest 16
mbs 2020-04-05 A3 Frve 2
mbs 2020-05-05 A3 Frve 10
mbs 2020-06-05 A3 Frve 15
mbs 2020-07-05 A3 Frve 20
mbs 2020-08-05 A3 Frve 33", header=TRUE, sep=" ") 

PlantComp$Date <- as.Date(PlantComp$Date, '%Y-%d-%m')

perc_cover_plot <- function(Species, Plot) { 
    sp <- Species
    pl <- Plot
    PlantCompSub <- subset(PlantComp, Species == sp & Plot == pl)
    return(plot(Cover ~ Date, data = PlantCompSub))
} 

perc_cover_plot("Cest", "A1")
```

[image]

```r
perc_cover_plot("Frve", "A3")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
PlantComp$Date <- as.Date(PlantComp$Date,'%Y-%d-%m')
#Function
perc_cover_plot <- function(x,Species, Plot) { 
  PlantCompSub <- dplyr::filter(x, Species == Species & Plot == Plot) 
  return(plot(Cover ~ Date, data = PlantCompSub))
} 

perc_cover_plot(PlantComp,Species = 'Cest',Plot = 'A1')
perc_cover_plot(PlantComp,Species = 'Frve',Plot = 'A3')
```

I actually noticed that you get the same plot because you have the same values in `Cover`, using your demo data of course. Your real dataframe must have different values.